# What is meaning of zip(kfold.split(X, Y) in sklearn

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, cross-validation

What is meaning of `zip(kfold.split(X, Y)` in sklearn?

```
for (train, test)in zip(kfold.split(X, Y)):
```

Comment: you might wanna read itertools doc's as well!

Answer (score 1):

With a bit more details, let's look at the shape of what `cv.split(...)` will give you:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
cv = KFold(n_splits=3)
splits = list(cv.split(X, y))
print(len(splits))
print(len(splits[0]))
print(splits)
```

```
3
2
[(array([ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,
        63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,
        76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,
        89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101,
       102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114,
       115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127,
       128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140,
       141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149]), array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49])), (array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
        26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49, 100, 101,
       102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114,
       115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127,
       128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140,
       141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149]), array([50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66,
       67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83,
       84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])), (array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
       85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]), array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112,
       113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125,
       126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138,
       139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149]))]
```

Therefore, `cv.splits(...)` have `n_splits` item. Each item is composed of 2 arrays: 1 training array, 1 testing array. The value in these arrays are the indices of the samples to be selected.

So you will be able to do:

```py
for train_idx, test_idx in cv.split(X, y):
    print(train_idx, test_idx)
```

However, adding `zip` will just pack the training and testing index together:

```py
for all_indices in zip(cv.split(X, y)):
    print(len(all_indices))  # equal to 2
```

Usually, you will be interested to not use `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

**Pack it in a tuple.**

`kfold.split(X, Y)` returns an iterable of indizes, you wrap them in a tuple object for train test indizes.